# excel match year and month in array

Tags: arrays, excel, date

I have an array of dates in column a that i would like to match against on year and month.

```
     A       B       C        D       E      F   G       H        I         J
1   date    name    Name    March   April   May June    July    August  September
2   13-04-2016  Lars    Lars    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   04-03-2016  Brian   Brian   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   01-01-2016  Lars    Erik    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   10-06-2016  Erik    Knut    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   31-07-2016  Erik    Soren   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I have tried with `$A:$A;"="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY());3;"");` where ;3; is the month of march. It evaluates to 0 on all accounts.

So how to adapt to make it count the number of dates matching the Year and Month (D2) for Lars (C2) in A:A?

Anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in D2 (and adapt as needed)

```
    =IF(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),3,1)=DATE(YEAR(A3),MONTH(A3),1),1,0)
```

`=IF( --Start the if`

`DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),3,1) -- Current year, 3rd month, 1st day`

`= --Equals (for if statement)`

`DATE(YEAR(A3),MONTH(A3),1) -- Year & month from Cell A3 & 1st day`

`,1,0) -- Print '1' if true else print '0'`

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to convert the date to text, then evaluate that in your formula.

Logic:

If Monthname(Date) = Top Row, then 1, else 0

Formula (placed in cell D2):

```
=if(text($A1,"mmmm")=D$1,1,0)
```

I have used the relative references for clicking and dragging.

Comment: Very elegant, but your missing an m ;) as the months are "long names" 
`=IF(TEXT($A2,"mmmm")=D$1,1,0)`